# Access an array in user Collection.[Meteor + React Native]

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I want to return the full array [votes] that is saved under the User Collection. 
**Here is the JSON structure**

```
{
    "_id" : "pziqjwGCd2QnNWJjX",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-21T22:06:41.930Z"),
    "emails" : [ 
        {
            "address" : "test@test.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
    "votes" : [ 
        {
            "ZyYZ4LDTaeWNMN9eE" : "yes"
        },
        {
            "DSHhkdsjkdhsddsqd" : "no"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I console.log that array ? The goal is to check if it exists before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you return just 1 document from the collection in MongoDB.

```
var user = Users.findOne({_id: your_given_id});

if(user && user.votes && user.votes.length){
    console.log(user.votes);
    return user.votes;
}
console.log('No Votes Found.');
return [];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the array exists and has elements:

```
const user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
const hasVotes = user && user.votes && typeof(user.votes) === 'object' && user.votes.length;
```

Comment: Note: findOne() return a single object while find().fetch() or find() on server returns array

Comment: `.find()` returns a *cursor*, not an *array*.

Comment: Sorry! in react native find returns array. In meteor returns cursor